# How do I change the host and port of paths in a servlet?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-filters, simple-framework

When I send a GET request to

```
Host: 1.1.1.1
Port: 9999
Path: /hello
```

I want a servlet that catches this request and sends a GET to

```
Host: 127.0.0.1
Port: 4444
Path: /hello?proxy=1.1.1.1
```

What's the easiest way to do this in Java? This will be used for integration tests, so I'd like to avoid having to change any of the main code's logic. Alternatively, it doesn't need to be a servlet. It can be a mock http service as well. I tried using simpleframework for this approach, but, and correct me if I'm wrong, it only picks up localhost.

Note I will need to redirect several GET requests with different hosts.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Tuckey's UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/). There is good doc and examples on their site.

Answer (score 0):

you can just redirect this request to your new host like:

```
response.sendRedirect("http://(your ip):4444/hello?proxy='1.1.1.1'");
```

Comment: What do I use to capture the request? I'm only familiar with capturing requests to my localhost 127.0.0.1 (using Tomcat/Jetty and Spring). How do I get the request data when the host is 1.1.1.1? Are there libraries or examples of that in Java?

Comment: You set your IP/Port of your Tomcat as the Proxy Server in your browser. But tomcat's not designed to be a proxy server.